# Adding filters to my page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, filters

I am creating a visual force page which display Opportunities:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opportunities" tabstyle="opportunity" sidebar="false">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunities">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="opportunitiy">
         <apex:column value="{!opportunitiy.name}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

It currently displays all Opportunities. The page has its own URL. I would like to be able to pass some query parameters into the URL (such as closed=true or amount>20,000) and then apply this filters so that only the Opportunities that match them are displayed.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way to do the is to create a custom controller (either stand alone or extending the standard controller) and perform your filtering there.

Answer (score 2):

For this you will have to create custom controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where I filtered the items in a listview using HTML5.  As I type, the characters entered filter the list down to matches anywhere in the string.  In this example I have a list of parts that can be hundreds if items long that is accessed using a mobile device.

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="partspage">                
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h2 id="partsHeader"></h2>
                <a href='#listpage' id="add" class='ui-btn-right' data-icon='back' data-theme="b">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="partList">            
                <ul id="pList" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview"  data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```